# Rails - devise with devise_token_auth not sending confirmation email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, access-token, rails-api, devise-confirmable

I work on project (ruby '2.2.0', rails '4.2.3') which use both standard devise user management (for web page) and devise_token_auth (for API part of the service). Everything works fine unless I

```
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

in the models/user.rb. Then sending confirmation emails after user registration does not occur.

I would be grateful for the solution of this problem.

My models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include devise modules.
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :confirmable, :omniauthable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  enum role: [:user, :vip, :admin]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :user
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # standard devise routes available at /users
  # NOTE: make sure this comes first!!!
  devise_for :users

  # token auth routes available at /api/v1/auth
  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same problem to you. This workaround helped me

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :confirmable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  after_create :send_confirmation_email, if: -> { !Rails.env.test? && User.devise_modules.include?(:confirmable) }

  private
  def send_confirmation_email
    self.send_confirmation_instructions
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code sends confirmation emails twice when registering by API.